# What is the spring boot dependency for JMS?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

The spring-boot guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/ uses spring-boot-starter-activemq and that in turn refers to spring-jms. If I want to use a different message broker and spring doesn't provide a starter jar for that particular message broker, how do I go about including the spring-jms in dependencies? Can I just include spring-jms or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s correct: you need to include `spring-jms` and
Vendor-specific dependency.

More info is in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jms).